# InvalidModuleError on local dev server when adding job to GAE TaskeQueue

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can someone please tell me how to resolve the GAE python 2.7 error shown below:

It just started happening after I upgraded GCloud and I don't understand what changed.
My import looks like this:

> from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

but I see some newer docs showing it like this:

> from google.appengine.api.taskqueue import taskqueue

But no clear deprecation or change notice and I'm afraid to deploy without understanding this first.

```
File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/common/async_tasks/push_notify.py", line 49, in registerPush
    taskqueue.add(target='task', queue_name=GAEQ_FOR_PUSH_NOTIFY, url=url, params=params )
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 2505, in add
    return Task(*args, **kwargs).add(
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 823, in __init__
    self.__resolve_hostname_and_target()
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 877, in __resolve_hostname_and_target
    host = self.__host_from_target(self.__target)
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 957, in __host_from_target
    instance=instance)
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/modules/modules.py", line 459, in get_hostname
    _ResultHook).get_result()
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/modules/modules.py", line 442, in _ResultHook
    _CheckAsyncResult(rpc, mapped_errors, [])
File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/modules/modules.py", line 147, in _CheckAsyncResult
    raise mapped_error()
InvalidModuleError
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dewey's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082371/invalidmoduleerror-on-local-dev-server-when-adding-job-to-gae-taskequeue#comment77281713_43099866) is the answer. if you have multiple services, [pass them all to `dev_appserver`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command), or at least any that you send taskqueue tasks to, e.g.:

`dev_appserver.py app.yaml tasks.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

OK....I found the problem.
The dev server was starting up without the taskqueue server running and so I guess the whole taskqueue package was not added to the google.api package....

Seems like a better error would be useful in that case....

Comment: how did you manage to start the taskqueue server in the dev environment?

Comment: It's been a while but I believe I included a separate app.yaml to start another microservice......
something like:
dev_appserver.py  app.yaml tasks.yaml

Comment: And when running what you suggest, you did not have the error 'google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute 'queue' for object of type AppInfoExternal.'?

Comment: I went and looked in that project to see how i solved this and I really cant remember.....

it might be as simple as adding this to your app.yaml 
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin

but I really can't remember for sure...